# How to add new field in revel controller

Tags: go, revel

i am using the validation example from the "revel" golang framework.
in the existing code, i have added new field. however, it is not recognizing the the contents of field and always throws the error.

here is the url: https://github.com/revel/examples/tree/master/validation

i have updated the entries in the model, controller and views. it is still throwing error.

Comment: Can someone please suggest ...

Comment: I suggest you to at least include the error you get. Nobody is going to know how to fix "The error".

Comment: resolved .. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i added the specific structure in the controller and its resolved...